# Is it good to encode each string in BASE64 for storing in Mysql?

Tags: android, mysql, json, encode

In my android app, each string stored in mysql database is encoded.
I do this because i have emoji in strings, and this is the only way i found.

Encode :

```
byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Decode :

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(userObject.getString("mystr"), Base64.DEFAULT);
String question = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The solution looks weird. That means you will not be able to do search in DB by these fields...like select *from XXX where myField like '%abc%'

Comment: yeah search would be a nightmare

Comment: Oh i forgot it !! So how can I store emoji ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you should save the text data in a simpler way. The problem you mention with emojis can be resolved changing the default character set of your database tables to utf8mb4.

You can accomplish that by doing the next steps:

1. Change the character set of your tables in the MySQL database using this SQL statement
   like this:

   `ALTER TABLE your_table_name charset=utf8mb4,
   MODIFY COLUMN your_fieldname1 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
   MODIFY COLUMN your_fieldname2 VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;`
2. Add this to the MySQL conf file and restart or reload the server (usually located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf or similar)

   `character-set-server = utf8mb4
   collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
3. Everytime you access your database in your Android application
   execute the next query: `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`
4. Query your text column as a normal String object in Java and you should see the emojis correctly displayed (no need for byte array or Base64 encoding).

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia:

Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to encode binary data that needs be stored and transferred over media that are designed to deal with textual data. This is to ensure that the data remains intact without modification during transport.

Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, I don't recommend passing everything from your app to the backend web service in Base64.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use a BLOB type field on your sqlite database...

> BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

[Sqlite.Org - DataTypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)